# Best practice for pairing samples for linear regression

Tags: regression

I am building linear regression models in R where the two distributions do not have ground truth or any obvious method for pairing samples from each.

What is the best practice for this scenario? The most obvious method would be to just sort both distributions but I'm wondering if there are any better methods. The other method I thought of would be to pair samples with nearest neighbor by percentile or rank.

What about if the two distributions have different amounts of samples? Which should be removed? Should samples ever be duplicated?

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide any more context to your data and are there any assumptions you can make?  If you can't make any assumptions, and there's no ground truth, then I'm not sure there's much you can do.

You suggest sorting, but how do you know they aren't inversely correlated?  Pairing by rank is the same story.  If the two distributions have a different number of samples, why would you expect there to be a pairing?

TLDR; What makes you think there is any relationship in this data?

Comment: Ok so the data is the runtime of a program. The same program with hundreds or thousands of runs. The amount of work is exactly the same across all runs. The difference between the two distributions is that they are different cpus. So we are attempting to build a model that takes the runtime of a program on one CPU to predict how it will run on a different CPU. We are using data such as Linux CPU timing metrics like User time, idle, kernel etc to then predict actual runtime.

Comment: So you want to predict total runtime from your 'target' CPU based on various timing metrics (user, kernel, idle, ...).  I am guessing your idea then, is to pair these timing metrics with one of the observations in the 'target' CPU in order to be able to perform your regression.  How many programs do you have this data for? Is it just the one?  Also, are there any other covariates that have been recorded (such as resident set size, hit-rate for cache, etc ...)?